# QML - How to have an animating background?

Tags: qt, animation, qml, qt-quick

I want to have a rectangle that has a background animation.
take a look at this

```
codepen.io/shshaw/pen/DxJka
```

How can I set this as my rectangle background so that it shows this animation in my application?

I want to be able to "load" premade css animations like the one in the link.

Comment: You would probably have the best luck with Image type loading your SVG and using XAnimators. Try it and post the code.

Answer (score 2):

If you think to use css, you can use a [WebView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebview-webview.html) and in this WebView you can load a html file from resource that read css file from resources too

Answer (score 1):

Within QML there is the possibility to use particle emitters, see [Qt Docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-effects-particles.html) for some information. The following should get you going a bit.

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.4
import QtQuick.Particles 2.0

Item {

    Rectangle {
        color: "#F9A72B"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    ParticleSystem { id: particles }

    ImageParticle {
        system: particles
        source: "qrc:/cloud.svg"
        alpha: 0.4
        alphaVariation: 0.2
    }

    Emitter {
        system: particles
        emitRate: 1
        lifeSpan: 70000
        velocity: PointDirection { x: -10; xVariation: -5; }
        size: 20
        sizeVariation: 10
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.margins: 5
    }
}
```

Obviously, you will have to play with the parameters to get it to your liking.

Comment: Thanks you, but i'm looking for a way to kind of load premade css animations  like the one i sent.

Comment: @Sherafati I don't think that possible in QML. Please update your question to state that you want that exact CSS incoorporated

Comment: I did so. So the only way is to build up animations from scratch myself?

Comment: Yes. QML is not HTML and is not CSS. You normally have to reimplement your example using the options that have been presented to you. I say normally, because depending on your platform, you do have the option of loading all of your HTML content into a WebEngineView and run it there as is. A WebEngineView is basically a browser embedded in your QML content. Note, that is not an option on mobile platforms where you must use WebView which is native.